# Name change from one element to another and value store

Tags: javascript, php, magento

i need to get the name and value from li  element  and display it after selection as the button value, what i need more is for that single value to be stored in a php var for latter submit, i got this far but now i am stuck and keep getting 1 size only

**CODE**

```
<button id="changename" class="btn dropdown-toggle size-selector-btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select your size <span class="caret" style="display: none;"></span>
</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu size-list" role="menu">
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
                        $attributeOptions = array();
                        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
                            foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
                                $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
                            }
                        }

                        $key = "Size";
                        foreach($attributeOptions[$key] as $size){ ?>

                                 <li id="<?php echo $size; ?>" onclick="changeName()"><?php echo $size; ?></li>
                    <?php    }



                       } ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                function changeName() {
                    document.getElementById("changename").innerHTML = "<?php echo $size; ?>";
                }
                </script>
```

Comment: Your formatting is so messed up its impossable to work out whats going on.

Comment: its updated now, sry for the mess

Comment: Ok, well ist still not great, with missing opening php tags and mismatched braces, but i think i have the gist of your problem

Answer (score 0):

OK, well there are 2 issues i can see. 1st that your third foreach loop looks like it should be nested within the others, but its not.

The second issue is that that you are missunderstanding how php and js work. Php is ran on the server before the page is rendered, so the value of $size in your js function will be whatever the LAST value of was.

To fix this, 1st nest the foreach correctly (when using php inline with html, i find its best to use the template syntax for blocks - eg `if: endif;`, `foreach: endforeach;` to aid readability), then adjust your js function to take a parameter, and pass that parameter in the onclick event by grabing the clicked elements id:

```
    <button id="changename" class="btn dropdown-toggle size-selector-btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select your size <span class="caret" style="display: none;"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu size-list" role="menu">
        <?php
        $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
        $attributeOptions = array();
        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) :
            foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) :
                $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
                $key = "Size";
                foreach($attributeOptions[$key] as $size):?>
                    <li id="<?php echo $size; ?>" onclick="changeName(this.id);"><?php echo $size; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
        ?>

    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    function changeName(size) {
        document.getElementById("changename").innerHTML = size;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok this works now, next problem is i need that selected value from js to get added to the $_product as size, because the product is configurable and cant be added to the cart unless the size is not set.